# What's the best open source solution to have a complete hourly-based backup system for a small-medium cluster in a datacenter?

Tags: backup, data-recovery

I'm looking for an open source solution for my small cluster of Linux servers (~20 Ubuntu-based nodes) that can provide an hourly-based (or even daily-based) backup and restore solution. I want it to work like Time Machine in Mac (even less, just take a backup every day) on a separate disk.

I have no idea what's the best solution, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shortly i think veeam would Server your need

Comment: SF tends to close questions asking for product suggestions, especially when they're vague and don't provide much information. If you edit your question to for techniques you might be ok. Also do you just want a solution to back up your VMs, the files on your VMs, or do you want a DR solution so you can run the VMs somewhere else if your hardware fails?

Comment: @djdomi It's not open source and it's not free

Comment: https://restic.net/ maybe?